# Assign name in Python based on variable and text

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to name my dataframe dynamically based on a variable and a text.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

var = 'A'
x = 'df_' + str(var)
x = pd.DataFrame()
x
```

The dataframe is now called:

```
x
```

But I want it to be called:

```
df_A
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT (solution):**

A better way to handle my problem is:

```
var = 'A'
globals()['df_'+ var] = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Yes, but don't.

Comment: Agreed. You *really* don't want to do this. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: You are setting x equal to a string, then setting x equal to a PD dataframe, which completely erased you setting it equal to a string.

Comment: "I want to name my dataframe dynamically based on a variable and a text." *don't do that*